# got error in accessing webservice through android application

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2, primitive, ksoap

i got this exceptions in when i m trying to invoke the webservice through android application

it shows following exceptions

```
04-30 11:51:06.558: E/Error :(297): Error on soapPrimitiveData() Transport endpoint is not connected
04-30 11:51:06.577: W/System.err(297): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Transport endpoint is not connected
04-30 11:51:06.587: W/System.err(297):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocketImpl(Native Method)
04-30 11:51:06.587: W/System.err(297):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:130)
04-30 11:51:06.597: W/System.err(297):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:246)
04-30 11:51:06.597: W/System.err(297):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:533)
04-30 11:51:06.607: W/System.err(297):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1055)
04-30 11:51:06.607: W/System.err(297):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
04-30 11:51:06.617: W/System.err(297):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)
04-30 11:51:06.617: W/System.err(297):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:927)
04-30 11:51:06.617: W/System.err(297):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:909)
04-30 11:51:06.628: W/System.err(297):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.sendRequest(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1325)
04-30 11:51:06.628: W/System.err(297):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequestInternal(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1656)
04-30 11:51:06.628: W/System.err(297):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequest(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1649)
04-30 11:51:06.637: W/System.err(297):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1243)
04-30 11:51:06.637: W/System.err(297):  at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:126)
04-30 11:51:06.647: W/System.err(297):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:179)
04-30 11:51:06.647: W/System.err(297):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
04-30 11:51:06.647: W/System.err(297):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:111)
04-30 11:51:06.657: W/System.err(297):  at com.practice.locationtracking.MainActivity.sendLocation(MainActivity.java:137)
04-30 11:51:06.667: W/System.err(297):  at com.practice.locationtracking.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:120)
04-30 11:51:06.667: W/System.err(297):  at com.practice.locationtracking.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:106)
04-30 11:51:06.678: W/System.err(297):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-30 11:51:06.678: W/System.err(297):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-30 11:51:06.687: W/System.err(297):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-30 11:51:06.687: W/System.err(297):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-30 11:51:06.697: W/System.err(297):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 11:51:06.697: W/System.err(297):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-30 11:51:06.697: W/System.err(297):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-30 11:51:06.707: W/System.err(297):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-30 11:51:06.717: W/System.err(297):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my webservice code

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class WebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection


    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function

    'Public Function SetLocationWebUser(ByVal sLattitude As Double, ByVal sLongitude As Double, ByVal sAddress As String, ByVal sLocality As String, ByVal sCountry As String, ByVal sUserId As String) As Boolean
    Public Function addLocationData(ByVal Latitude As String, ByVal Longitude As String, ByVal UserName As String) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim sdr As New DataSet()
            Dim dt As New DataTable()

            'conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = 62.75.229.51; Initial Catalog = Silver_WebPH; User id =Silver_Webph; password =sbyadmin"
            'Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO MAP (LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,SERVER_DATE,ADDRESS,LOCALITY,COUNTRY,USER_ID,WEB_ENTRY) VALUES (" + sLattitude.ToString + "," + sLongitude.ToString + ",getdate(),'" + sAddress.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sLocality.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sCountry.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sUserId + "',1 )"
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=KunalShah-PC;Initial Catalog=Location;Integrated Security=True"
            Dim strsql As String = "INSERT INTO LocatioData values (@Longitude, @Latitide, @UserName)"

            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = strsql
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Longitude", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Longitude
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Latitude", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Latitude
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = UserName

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

the function which send the location from my android application is as follows..

```
private boolean sendLocation(String latitude, String longitude, String UserName)
    {
        boolean flag = false;
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/addLocationData";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "addLocationData";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject (NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("Latitude",latitude);
        request.addProperty("Longitude", longitude);
        request.addProperty("UserName", UserName);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        System.out.println(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try
        {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive result= (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String res_string = result.toString();
            System.out.println(res_string);
        }
        catch(SocketException ex)
        {
            Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
        return flag;
    }
```

can any one help me with the code, can any one tell me where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY this:

final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/addLocationData";

```
final String METHOD_NAME = "addLocationData";
SoapObject request = new SoapObject (NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;     
envelope.xsd = Constants.NAME_SPACE;
envelope.enc = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Entity";
 request.addProperty("Latitude",latitude);
request.addProperty("Longitude", longitude);
request.addProperty("UserName", UserName);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(
        URL, 60000);
androidHttpTransport
        .setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");

try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME, envelope);
    } 
catch (Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
Log.e("result", "" + result.toString());
```

Comment: replace the line envelope.xsd = Constants.NAME_SPACE; with envelope.xsd = NAME_SPACE;

Comment: java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500
it throws this exception now.
and then the application crashes.

Comment: had u added the permission for    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  and added the ksoap library to project.

Comment: Rest of the code is working fine if more help needed just type the code again as u edited it now.

Comment: Which ksoap lib are you using @deepak825?? I am not getting AndroidHttpTransport